# Track conversions from facebook app install ads with iTunes Analytics

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, google-analytics

Is it possible to track conversions from facebook app install ads using [iTunes Analytics](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-analytics/)?

Currently Facebook strips out campaign links when setting up the advertisment.  Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclosure: I built a lot of the [branch.io](https://branch.io) service, and I spent at least 18 hours a day thinking about mobile linking.

Unfortunately, since Facebook routes the user straight to their native App Store page, you can't append parameters to track page views and installs. Hopefully this will change soon, but for now, it's impossible.

If you're looking for free-to-use install and down funnel event tracking back to the Facebook install ad, we recently built out a custom integration with Facebook that allows Branch to tell you which individual user originated from a specific Facebook install ad. To do so, once you integrate with the tool, you simply need to drop a Branch link into the Deep Link field of the ad builder to start reporting on installs in realtime. We even tell you that info client side, so you can show a different custom welcome to users who come from different ads. It's not App Store page views, but you can know how many folks make it through that gauntlet overall.

I actually also just wrote a guide on how to do this if it helps:
https://dev.branch.io/recipes/advertising_facebook